# Kivy program: how to change focus in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

When I run a kivy program in Pycharm, the kivy window doesn't have the default kivy app title, the kivy logo in top-left nor the 3 control buttons in the top-right. It completely occupies my screen and I can't do anything anymore. I'm on Windows 10. Need help, please.
I'm using Python 3.9.0, kivy 2.0.0

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MainWidget(Widget):
  pass

class boxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.orientation = "vertical"
      item1 = Button(text='a button')
      self.add_widget(item1)
      item2 = Label(text='a label')
      self.add_widget(item2)
      item3 = Button(text='a button')
      self.add_widget(item3)

class myApp(App):
 pass

myApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Windows doesn't have those control buttons, those buttons are on Mac. Windows has the same functionality, in the form of the close button, the restore down button, and the minimize button.

Answer (score 0):

the key is the configuration which can either be modified using the config.ini file or the config object.

on my windows system the config file is in C:\users<username>.kivy\config.ini
and you may have to change Windows Explorer to show hidden items if you want to see the .kivy directory.

inside that configuration file, the borderless property being set to 1 could cause this behavior so set this to 0.  The curios thing is that by default this should have been 0 so I don't know why it would have changed.

```
[graphics]
borderless = 0
```

and you may also be interested in these properties

```
width = 1200
height = 600
fullscreen = 0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from kivy import Config
Config.set("graphics", "fullscreen", "0")
```

RTFM -> [go here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html?highlight=config#module-kivy.config)